# How can I calculate the length of an array of objects with reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I have this simple function, and I am just trying to get the length of this array of objects. For instance I want to return `3` in that case below. I could use `.length()` but I want to explore more with the reduce method.

```js
function getSum(data) {
  const totalNum = data.reduce((sum, a) => sum + a.id, 0);
  return totalNum
}

console.log(getSum([
  {id: 'ddd6929eac', isComplete: true},
  {id: 'a1dd9fbd0', isComplete: true},
  {id: 'afa8ee064', isComplete: false}
]))
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: what property would you like to sum?

Comment: the only thing that correlates with your expected output is returning `data.length`

Comment: A better exploration would be to add a `value: N` property to each item and sum that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the equivalent  of `data.length` would be:

```js
data.reduce(sum => sum + 1, 0);
```

But I don't see why you would do that unless you're trying to exclude blank values.

Comment: is because I am starting to do a progress bar and need also to manipulate some other values of these objects so is kinda necessary at least how I see it to loop to do other calculations as well

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can just add index:

```
const totalNum = data.reduce((sum, a, index) => index+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add one for each item in the array.

```js
function getSum(data) {
    return data.reduce((sum, a) => sum + 1, 0);
}

const
    data = [{ id: 'ddd6929eac', isComplete: true }, { id: 'a1dd9fbd0', isComplete: true }, { id: 'afa8ee064', isComplete: false }];

console.log(getSum(data));
```